# Neural network model predicting unexpected results

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I want to create a CNN which is able to play a car racing game by itself.
I have trained the model with 30.000 samples, my features (x_test) are frames and my labels (y_test) are w a d keys (one-hot encoded) 
But my model is predicting this instead of predicting
three probabilities:

```python
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]
```

Is the problem in my model structure or do I need a larger data set?

My code is:

1. Training

   ```python
       classifier = create_model()
           train_data=np.load('data1/final_data.npy')
           for i in range(52):
               file_name = 'data2/training_data-{}.npy'.format(i)
               train_data_2=np.load(file_name)
               train_data=np.concatenate((train_data,train_data_2))    
           shuffle(train_data)
           x=train_data[:,0]
           y=train_data[:,1]
           train_data=[]
           x=x.tolist()
           x=np.array(x)
           y=y.tolist()
           y=np.array(y)
           classifier.fit(x,y, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
           classifier.save('/output/model.model')
   ```
2. Model

   ```python
   def create_model():
       classifier = Sequential()
       classifier.add(Conv2D(96,(3,3),input_shape=(120,160,3),activation='relu'))
       classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
       classifier.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu'))
       classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
       classifier.add(Conv2D(384,(3,3),activation='relu'))
       classifier.add(Conv2D(384,(3,3),activation='relu'))  
       classifier.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu'))
       classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
       classifier.add(Flatten())
       classifier.add(Dense(units = 2048, activation = 'relu'))
       classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
       classifier.add(Dense(units = 2048, activation = 'relu'))
       classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
       classifier.add(Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))
       classifier.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
       metrics = ['accuracy'])  
       return classifier
   ```
3. Tester

   ```python
           def straight():
               ReleaseKey(A)
               ReleaseKey(D)
               PressKey(W)
           def left():
               ReleaseKey(D)
               PressKey(W)
               PressKey(A)

           def right():
               ReleaseKey(A)
               PressKey(W)
               PressKey(D)

           def main():
               model=load_model('model.model')

               for i in list(range(5))[::-1]:
                   print(i+1)
                   time.sleep(1)

               paused = False
               while(True):

                   if not paused:
                       screen = grab_screen(region=(0,64,640,480))
                       screen = cv2.resize(screen, (160,120))
                       screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                       screen = np.expand_dims(screen, axis = 0)
                       prediction = model.predict(screen)[0]
                       print(prediction)

                       maxval=max(prediction)

                       if prediction[1] == maxval:
           #                straight()
                           print('straigh',maxval)
                       elif prediction[2] == maxval:
           #                right()
                           print('right',maxval)
                       elif prediction[0] == maxval:
           #                left()
                           print('left',maxval)
           #
           #        keys = key_check()
           #
           #        if 'P' in keys:
           #            if paused:
           #                paused = False
           #                time.sleep(1)
           #            else:
           #                paused = True
           #                ReleaseKey(A)
           #                ReleaseKey(W)
           #                ReleaseKey(D)
           #                time.sleep(1)

           main()
   ```

Comment: Why did you decide to train this for 5 epochs? What is the train and validation/test accuracy after those 5 epochs? Is the dataset balanced?

Comment: loss: 10.6982 - acc: 0.3363. My dataset is balanced. Is it necessary to provide validation set other than training set while training?

Comment: You should have a validation set, in order to detect overfitting. The loss is high and accuracy is low, you either have to train the model for longer or maybe make a deeper model. You should adjust epochs and learning rate before even looking at the predictions.

Comment: But at least i should give me some numeric values(Probabilities) rather than   predicting [ 1.  0.  0.] for every test sample. Even without loading weights to model it gave me something like [ 0.45156  0.32545  0.195455]

Comment: [1 0 0 ] are actually probabilities, just that all the mass is concentrated on the first element.

Comment: model.evaluate(x_test,y_test,batch_size=32)
2798/2798 [==============================] - 705s      
Out[11]: [10.651307494918136, 0.33917083643946672]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be resolved by creating a deeper neural network.